# Node and relationship creation in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a data set, which looks like this
[image: People data]

Now, as one can see that a single person has multiple skillid, along with this data, i also have a skill_ref table, which has 2 columns(skillid and skillname) so from the image above, i can look and say that last person has multiple skills, Now, i want this data to be put in Neo4j, with person and skillname as node, and a relationship of has_skill. But i dont know how to handle the multiple instances, if i split the skillid , then i will have multiple instances of person name, but this is not what i want, i want something like this
[image: Graph Visualization]

in the graph,the center node is the name of the person and the others have skill name, with the arrows pointing a relation has_skill.
I am new to neo4j as well as cypher, any help guys will be highly appreciated.

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///people_data.csv" AS line
CREATE (p:Person{id:line.people_uid})
WITH line, p
SET p.firstName = line.first_name,p.lastname=line.last_name
WITH line,split(line.skillid,' ') as skill_ids
UNWIND skill_ids as skill_Id
MERGE (skill:Skill{id:skill_Id})
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///skills_ref.csv" AS line
WITH line
MERGE(skill:line.skillid{name:line.skillname})
CREATE (p)-[:HAS_SKILL]->(skill)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got the right idea.

The general approach is to first MERGE (or CREATE) the `:Person node`, then split() the `skillid` into a list of skill ids, UNWIND the skill id list into rows, then MERGE the skill for the given id (and make sure you have an index or unique constraint on `:Skill(id)`), then MERGE (or CREATE) the relationship between the :Person node and the :Skill.

Here's an example, loading from a CSV file:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///your.file.url" AS line
CREATE (p:Person{id:line.people_uid})
WITH line, p
SET p.firstName = line.f_name ... <same for the rest of the properties>
UNWIND split(line.skillid, ' ') as skillId
MERGE (skill:Skill{id:skillId})
CREATE (p)-[:HAS_SKILL]->(skill)
```

EDIT

Regarding the revised query you're attempting, it's actually better to use separate queries for each csv load, using the first to create the nodes and merge the relationships, and the second just to match/merge to skills and add the skill name:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///people_data.csv" AS line
CREATE (p:Person{id:line.people_uid})
SET p.firstName = line.first_name, p.lastname=line.last_name
WITH line, split(line.skillid, ' ') as skill_ids
UNWIND skill_ids as skill_Id
MERGE (skill:Skill{id:skill_Id})
CREATE (p)-[:HAS_SKILL]->(skill)
```

Then your next query:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///skills_ref.csv" AS line
MERGE (skill:Skill{id:line.skillid})
SET skill.name = line.skillname
```

Remember that you should have an a unique constraint created on :Skill(id) and :Person(id) first.

Comment: Thanks @InverseFalcon for replying to my query, the problem is that i have two different CSVs, one with the sample i showed you as an image, and other the skill_ref one(which has skill id and name), the merging of these two is not possible as again i have multiple skill ids in a cell for people data(image). Can you please shed more light on to your solution, and thanks again mate for the quick suggestion

Comment: Let me explain the line `UNWIND split(line.skillid, ' ') as skillId`. This takes your string of multiple skill ids and changes them into a list of skill ids. [UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/clauses/unwind/) then emits multiple rows, one per element in the list, so where before you only had one row per person and a string of ids, you would now have (per person) a number of rows equal to the number of ids. MERGE lets you create a node for each id (but never creating more than one for the same id).

Comment: Later you can process the other CSV, using MERGE to the :Skill nodes by id and adding the skill name.

Comment: Hi @InverseFalcon, i tried what you explained, please find the updated code in the original question as edited, the query is not throwing any results, your guidance will be highly appreciable, i am new to this stuff, and CQL is getting a bit on me. If you can, please help me.

Comment: Updated my answer, you should use two separate queries for each csv load.

Comment: Also, you mentioned a line where you merged id with skill_id, how can i merge people id with skill id?

Comment: That's what the creation of the relationship is for. You've created your :Person nodes by id, you've merged your :Skill nodes by id, then you created the relationship between them. If you want to see the result after running these, try this: `MATCH (p:Person) with p limit 20 MATCH path =
 (p)-[:HAS_SKILL]->(skill) RETURN path`. Adjust the limit or remove as you like